# Attaching a Body to another, without the new body impacting the physics of the first in ANY WAY

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

Basically I want to add a vision / sight cone to an enemy body,

So I have the sight cone body, and enemy body, but every joint or weld I have tried so far has caused the sight cone to severely affect and disrupt the physics and movement of my enemy, most of the time causing the poor guy to go into tailspins.

I only want the sight cone as a sensor, a sensor that has NO physics impact whatsoever on its parent body (the enemy) except simply to stay stuck to it as it moves, matching its position and rotation. but all I can seem to find is weighted attachments, that set up new anchors and whole new physics properties to me new joined body.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fixture.IsSensor = true;` is what you need. A sensor will detect collisions but will not automatically respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a joint, what you probably want to do is add sensor `Fixture` to the original `Body`.

The code would be something like this:

```
var fixture = FixtureFactory.Attach...(..., body);
fixture.IsSensor = true;
```

Sensor fixtures take part in collision *detection* but not collision *response* (basically so they can fire collision events when they "sense" something).

Sensor fixtures can have mass, so be sure to set its density to 0, otherwise it can affect the physics behaviour of the parent body.